# Como listar resultado da contagem de horas do database

Tags: php, mysql

Estou querendo listar um registro da tabela e exibir a soma de horas reportadas, mas não estou conseguindo.

A tabela reports tem o campo registration e duration

```
registration       duration
    2501       00:40:00(timestamp)  
    2501       01:20:00(timestamp)  
    5531       01:20:00(timestamp)
```

Quero listar a soma de horas(duration) para cada registro(registration)

```
$hours = mysql_query("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( duration ) ) )  AS duration_sum FROM reports");                                                 
$horas = mysql_result($hours,0,"duration_sum");
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($horas)){

    <tr>
    <td align="center"><div align="left"><? echo($row[1]); ?></div></a></td>
    <td align="center"><div align="center"><? echo($row[2]); ?></div></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Retorna algum erro? Qual é a saida? O que o seu select esta retornando?

Comment: retorna: Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/fabvirtual/public_html/portal/comgap-hours.php on line 127

Comment: Qual é a linha 127?

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_row($horas)){

Comment: E executando o comando diretamente no banco, o SELECT, qual é a saida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplo:

```
$hours = mysql_query("SELECT registration, duration FROM reports GROUP BY registration");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($hours)){ 
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div align="left"><? echo $row['registration']; ?></div></a></td>
        <td align="center"><div align="center"><? echo $row['duration']; ?></div></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Agrupando pelo campo **registration** vejo que irá retornar a soma da duração de cada **registration** que acredito é o que você quer. Ele vai agrupar os valores (do campo **registration**) que são iguais e vai fazer a soma da duração para cada **registration**. Compreende?

Diferença entre **mysql_fetch_assoc** e **mysql_fetch_row**:

mysql_fetch_row — Obtém uma linha como uma array numérica

mysql_fetch_assoc — Obtém um linha do resultado como uma matriz associativa

O método **mysql_result**:

Retorna dados do resultado.

> mysql_result() retorna o conteúdo de uma célula do resultado MySQL. O argumento field(campo) pode ser o índice do campo, o nome do campo, o a tabela ponto o nome do campo(tabela.campo). Se o nome da coluna usa apelido ('select foo as bar from...'), use o apelido ao invés do nome da coluna.

**Observações**:

Considere substituir mysql_* por mysqli_*, porque o qual você esta utilizando encontra-se obsoleto.

**Referências e outras informações**:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-result.php

Comment: De onde vem $soma?

Comment: Obrigado, alterei a resposta e me esqueci de substituir o $soma.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!!